# ARM board can't use NFS on 22.04

Tags: nfs, arm

I've been using NFS mounted root for an ARM board for a long time up to Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed a new version 22.04 on a new computer and it doesn't work any more. I can mount a directory on the new host from the old one, but NOT from the ARM.

Here is the message:

```
eth0: link down
IP-Config: Guessing netmask 255.255.255.0
IP-Config: Complete:
      device=eth0, addr=192.168.1.6, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=255.255.255.255,
     host=192.168.1.6, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=192.168.1.4, rootpath=
Looking up port of RPC 100003/2 on 192.168.1.4
eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
Root-NFS: Unable to get nfsd port number from server, using default
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 192.168.1.4
nfs: server 192.168.1.4 not responding, timed out
```

Here is the same when it works using the old one:

```
eth0: link down
IP-Config: Guessing netmask 255.255.255.0
IP-Config: Complete:
      device=eth0, addr=192.168.1.6, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=255.255.255.255,
     host=192.168.1.6, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=192.168.1.2, rootpath=
Looking up port of RPC 100003/2 on 192.168.1.2
eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC5E1
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 192.168.1.2
VFS: Mounted root (nfs filesystem).
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

```
No.     Time    Source  Destination     Protocol        Length  Info
8569    7.519158427     192.168.1.6     192.168.1.4     Portmap 130     V2 GETPORT Call (Reply In 8570) NFS(100003) V:2
UDP
8570    7.519427844     192.168.1.4     192.168.1.6     Portmap 70      V2 GETPORT Reply (Call In 8569) PROGRAM_NOT_AVAI
LABLE
8622    7.525121157     192.168.1.6     192.168.1.4     Portmap 130     V2 GETPORT Call (Reply In 8625) MOUNT(100005) V:
1 UDP
8625    7.525387948     192.168.1.4     192.168.1.6     Portmap 70      V2 GETPORT Reply (Call In 8622) Port:32838
8637    7.526350163     192.168.1.6     192.168.1.4     MOUNT   82      V1 NULL Call (Reply In 8640)
8640    7.526488086     192.168.1.4     192.168.1.6     MOUNT   66      V1 NULL Reply (Call In 8637)
8648    7.526967595     192.168.1.6     192.168.1.4     MOUNT   130     V1 MNT Call (Reply In 8650) /home/super8
8650    7.529473271     192.168.1.4     192.168.1.6     MOUNT   102     V1 MNT Reply (Call In 8648)
8663    7.531654612     192.168.1.6     192.168.1.4     NFS     82      V2 NULL Call
8664    7.531679818     192.168.1.4     192.168.1.6     ICMP    110     Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
8685    8.628828192     192.168.1.6     192.168.1.4     NFS     82      [RPC retransmission of #8663]V2 NULL Call
8686    8.628878863     192.168.1.4     192.168.1.6     ICMP    110     Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
8721    10.828441664    192.168.1.6     192.168.1.4     NFS     82      [RPC retransmission of #8663]V2 NULL Call
8722    10.828494033    192.168.1.4     192.168.1.6     ICMP    110     Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
```

Comment: Have you tried probing the server from the client using showmount? ex. `showmount -e 192.168.2.4`

Comment: I have added a WireShark log to the original post. Comments are limited in size.

Comment: ''' showmount -e 192.168.1.4
Export list for 192.168.1.4:
/home 10.0.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24```

Comment: Don't forget this isn't a forum (but a Q&A site), *comments* are intended for readers asking for details/clarifications from the *Original Poster*, the OP is expected to reply via edits or additional details in the question itself (comments can then be removed; OP isn't supposed to reply via comment)

Comment: Have you installed the `nfs-common` package for NFS support?